# gulpfile throws error events.js:154

Tags: javascript, gulp

What's listed below is throwing an error. It's my gulpfile, so I'm trying to figure it out. It's firing on events.js:154. Throw er; //Unhandled 'eerror' event.

Any idea what is wrong here? It was fine last night, it was even writing a new main.min.js file to the js folder. What is wrong and how do i get the uglifying to work again?

```
/* Required */
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

/* Scripts Task */
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src(['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/js/**/*min.js'])
    .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});

/* Watch Task */
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

/* Default Task */
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to execute `scripts` again in your `default` task. Its already being executed in your `watch` task

Comment: Still throwing an error, doesn't uglify main.js. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Do you have gulp available globally?

Comment: Yes, I had everything working fine last night. I tried adding gulp-sass and compiling my style.scss...that caused main.js not to minify so then i tried tweaking it more and got both to fail. Now i'm lost somewhere in the middle trying to get back the js minification functionality. After that go with a diff sass plugin.

To add, when i npm install <package>, it doesn't auto save to my package.json, I have to manually edit it. Was that me not configuring it properly? If I need to add other files let me know.

THANK YOU

Comment: When running gulp, I'm getting errors in node_modules\uglify-js, i'm assuming its my piping causing an error?

Comment: Try removing everything from your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`. Just ensure that you have all the required dependencies in your package.json. Also, you need to do `npm i --save-dev <package>` or `npm i --save <package>` to save it to package.json

Comment: Hey Aditya, could you see what you think? Thank you

So I got my gulp task runner completely configured. Love it. Now, I'm easing into Node + Express. My question is: I can start the express server, then bash out my gulp task runner in another window...the express server runs index.js to port 3000, gulp runs my index.html on 3001. How can i merge these and use them together on the same port to begin development via html/css/angular? It is okay that gulp runs on a diff port? Will i be able to work on index.html and use angular/mongo etc with gulp and express running on diff ports? THANKS